# How to print the name and value of each Outlook Contact field with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

For each Outlook Contact I need to grab the name and value of each field.
Eg.

```
    FirstName:  John
    LastNmae:  Doe
... etc.
```

How can I go about this without referencing each field individually?

With the code below I can print the name of each property, but I don't know how to print the value.  The line that is commented out throws an error:  "Invalid procedure call or argument"

```
Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Dim Contact As ContactItem
Dim i As Integer

    For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
        id = Contact.EntryID
        Debug.Print Contact.FirstName
        Debug.Print id
        For i = 0 To Contact.ItemProperties.Count - 1
            Debug.Print Contact.ItemProperties(i).Name
            'Debug.Print Contact.ItemProperties(i).Value
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Did you *try* iterating the contacts? And what do you mean with "without referencing each field individually"?

Comment: There's a big problem with outlook's application tree in this regard... You can have multiple outlook sessions with multiple inboxes with multiple address lists with address entries. . . Use a foreach to get down to the olOutlookContactAddressEntry... but even then --- you need all the fields? I doubt it.

Comment: Why do you need **all* properties? If your code is not aware of it, what good would it do?

Comment: I've added some code to the original post to help clarify what I'm trying to do.  I need all of the Contact's properties because I don't know which Contact properties will be used for every user.  For example, most users probably don't use the Web Page property, but maybe some do or will, so I want to grab it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of grabbing all the names of all address lists in the current session.

You can find all the properties for the object at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320232.aspx

For obtaining the object's properties' names and evaluating them, see a TypeLib reference.  (http://visualbasic.happycodings.com/applications-vba/code19.html may or may not apply)

```
Sub getContact()

    Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
    Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    Dim Contact As ContactItem
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
        ID = Contact.EntryID
        Debug.Print Contact.FirstName
        Debug.Print ID
        For i = 0 To Contact.ItemProperties.Count - 1
        Debug.Print Contact.ItemProperties(i).Name
        ' Doesn't work for object propertieties, like application.
        ' (Do Error Handling)
        Deubg.Print CallByName(Contact, Contact.ItemProperties(i).Name, VbGet) 
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: The OP asks how to print the name of each available property, not each address entry.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko for which I provided the link about TypeLib, but I believe it is better to simply look up the object's properties and choose which ones you need.

Comment: @CodyG. I'm only interested in a user's local contact folder, not the entire AddressList.  I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate TypeLib into my code above, but no luck so far.

Comment: @SeanS what about CallByName? See updated code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278760.aspx